# Servlet Mapping for Weblogic 8, How to?

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic, web.xml

I have a WAR file with a web application that has been deployed to a weblogic stream.

The JSP part works fine, but it can't find the servlets. Possible due to the lack of mapping in my web.xml file.

I was working fine on Tomcat 6, but can't seem to find using weblogic.

I used annotation @WebServlet("/actionOne") but this doens't seem to work.

I am a little confused about how to map these correctly via the web.xml file.

the servlets are .java files and located at WEB-INF/classes/com/foo/bar/

So far I have added the following the web.xml file but the servlet-mapping section has me confused.

```
     <servlet>
            <servlet-name>actionOne</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.foo.bar.actionOne</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>actionTwo</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.foo.bar</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

Hopefully the above is correct, the next section I'm not sure how to use and would appreciate some help.

```
   <servlet-mapping>
             <servlet-name>actionOne</servlet-name>
             <url-pattern>/actionOne</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

The servlets are being called from the jsp via a Form action="actionOne"

Comment: `WEB-INF/classes/com/foo/bar/` contains your servlet classes? Which one of them was mapped to `/actionOne`?

Answer (score 0):

My mapping was correct, it seems the issue was related to a different version of servlet.api in the weblogic modules folder. 2.5 instead of 3.0. This resolved the issue.